# How to convert dates with alphabetic months to timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

What is the most efficient way to convert list itmes like

```
02/Oct/2013:20:18:18
```

to timestamp, using Python?
I need to convert HUGE log files in which lines are going to be processed based on their timestamps. so need a really fast transformation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) is the way to go. It will accept arbitrary time formats and convert it into a `struct_time` type object.

Additionally, you can use `time.mktime()` to get the unix-timestamp from the `struct_time` object.

EDIT: (Adding example)

Taking your example data, you'd do something like this (python shell:

```
>>> time.strptime("02/Oct/2013:20:18:18", "%d/%b/%Y:%X")
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=20, tm_min=18, tm_sec=18, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=275, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime("02/Oct/2013:20:18:18", "%d/%b/%Y:%X"))
    1380725298.0
```

BTW, if you need to understand the format specifiers for the date, have a look at the `date` manpage.

Comment: can you provide an example of each usage please?

Answer (score 0):

simply use python datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('02/Oct/2013:20:18:18','%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```