# Converting http request time to unix timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime

Folks, 
  How would I convert the following string to a unix epoch timestamp?

```
Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:55:44 GMT
```

I can pull in the local http timestamp via the following:

```
In [53]: now = datetime.now()

In [54]: stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())

In [55]: print format_date_time(stamp)
Thu, 03 Oct 2013 16:24:59 GMT
```

and how would i convert the resulting unix timestamp back to the above format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import time
>>> int(time.time())
1380817337
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert to timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime 

ts = datetime.strptime("Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:55:44 GMT", "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z").strftime("%s")
print ts  # '1380804944'
```

Convert back to the original format:

```
from datetime import datetime

dtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(int('1380804944')).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z GMT")
print dtime      # 'Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:55:44 '
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import email
>>> time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate("Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:55:44 GMT"))
1380804944.0
```

And back:

```
>>> f = 1380804944.0
>>> email.utils.formatdate(f, False, True)
'Thu, 03 Oct 2013 12:55:44 GMT'
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question earlier today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150768/how-to-convert-dates-with-alphabetic-months-to-timestamp/19150805#19150805). Let me know if that works for you.

Basically you need to look at the `time.strptime()` and `time.mktime()` functions.

In your case, the format specifier would be:

`time.strptime("Thu, 03 Oct 2013 14:55:44 GMT", "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z")`

Comment: Does not quite work for me.... print time.strptime("Thu, 03 Oct 2013 16:24:59 GMT") returns: ValueError: time data 'Thu, 03 Oct 2013 16:24:59 GMT' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'

Comment: @Clustermagnet Updated answer with the exact function call you would need to use. You missed the format specifier.